# Syntax to create a file list

Tags: linux, path, syntax

When I try to create a list of the files on a CD and to save it as a text file, something must be wrong with my syntax. Entering the command:

`gz@gcomputer:/media$ ls -aRl1 >> /home/gz/texte1/infos/DateilisteCD_1.txt`

leads to the result:

> bash: /home/gz/texte1/infos/DateilisteCD_1.txt: Ist kein Verzeichnis

It means "is not a directory".

I got the paths with the names of the directories from the browser (Nautilus). They all exist.

What is the correct syntax please?

Comment: Does the directory `/home/gz/texte1/infos/` exist?

Comment: @Matthew the error means that _something_ of that name exists but it is not a directory.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you are treating a file as a directory:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jun 13 19:40 foo       <-- a directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jun 13 19:40 foo.txt   <-- a file
$ ls > foo
bash: foo: Is a directory
$ ls > foo/bar  ## WORKS
$ ls > foo.txt/bar
bash: foo.txt/bar: Not a directory
```

So, one of the names in the path you specify exists but is not a directory. Check that each of `/home/gz/texte1/infos/` is actually a directory and not a file.

Comment: They are all existing directories. Only the last item in the list is a text file. As I have written I found the path in the browser. But in the mean time I got an idea what could be the problem. As shown in my listing I am on the main directory of the CD, named media. It is necessary to be there because the directory of the CD should be read. But may be the path of the output is searched also on the CD, where it does not exist of course. How should be the syntax when my path is on the hard disk?

Comment: @Zeyer The path you are usiing is on the hard disk, not the cd. One of e directories in the oath is probably a file.